# Firebase Phone Auth not receiving silent notification on SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I am trying to implement phone auth in SwiftUI using Firebase. I keep getting the following error in the console:

```
If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton: method.
```

I have not disabled swizzling from what I know and I have tried different things.
I set-up my firebase project correctly, anyone else facing the same problem?

I looked up in the documentation and I found a part about this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
    completionHandler(.noData)
    return
  }
  // This notification is not auth related, developer should handle it.
}
```

But I don't know where to put it or how to declare it.

Tried doing the following but nothing changes:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import GoogleMaps

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
        fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
        completionHandler(.noData)
        return
      }
      // This notification is not auth related, developer should handle it.
    }
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
      for urlContext in URLContexts {
          let url = urlContext.url
          Auth.auth().canHandle(url)
      }
      // URL not auth related, developer should handle it.
    }
}

@main
struct partidulverdeApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyAaze5cpEcJUgw2WFgLhlTWYr9ZP4fyDNk")
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
                Auth.auth().canHandle(url)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, swizzling enabled and always defaults to captcha instead of silent notification. The place to put that method would be in your AppDelegate class, but I've tried implementing that too and it did nothing. It seems like swizzling is broken...